Custom Tailwind background image works for a specific image, not for the others
I use React, NextJS and Tailwind.
I want to use some images as background for some cards elements.
I first store the images names in an array.
const symbols = ['boat_2.png', 'boat.png', 'tortue.jpg', 'surf.jpg'];
Then I map the array and pass the name in the child elements.
                    {symbols.map((symbol, index) => (
                        <ChildElement
                            key = {index}
                            symbol = {symbol}
                        />
                    ))}

In the child element I use the name to fit the the Tailwind syntax : bg-[url('imagepath')]
    var bgImg = "bg-[url('../public/" + symbol + "')]"
    console.log(bgImg)

The path is correctly displayed in the console.
Finally I use the bgImg variable in the className for my div element.
    return (
        <div
            className={`${bgImg} bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat aspect-[5/7] border-2 rounded-xl border-black`}
        >
        </div>
    )

The problem is only the boat.png is working.
All others images are not displayed.
I tried to access my images (through localhost:3000/surf.jpg for exemple) and it works.
I restart my browser, visual studio. Nothing worked.
I though it could be the image format. So I copied my boat.png in the folder and renamed it boat_2.png.
boat.png still works but boat_2.png doesnt.
I tried to make custom backgroundImage in the tailwind.config.ts like
      backgroundImage: {
        'surf': "url('../public/surf.jpg')",
      },

This last method (using className = bg-surf) worked. But I want to understand why the first method works only for le boat.png image.
Since it's a one-time use background images I dont want to specify them in the tailwind.config.ts and would like to fix the first method. (Maybe I'm wrong and should use this way)
Thanks for any advices

https://chat.openai.com/share/dfff83ce-0081-44f9-a394-ed9fbba8650c
chat gpt answer... it might help

use /public/image.png for the image path, remove the .. you probably won't need this. And store only image path in the bgImg and use it in className like this bg-[url('${bgImg}')]

Tailwind cannot handle dynamically concatenated strings to form a single class name, as the full class name does not appear in the source code.
See the documentation:

If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS

You can use an inline style instead.
<div className={yourClassName}
     style={{backgroundImage: "url('../public/" + symbol + "')"}}>
    { /* children */ }
</div>


This is most likely postcss thats not got the classes included so they are being striped out when your app builds. I think you can try whitelisting those, or by whitelisting a regex of bg-*, which might not work.
But if all else fails you can just use css directly in the div like so:
<div style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(...)'}} />

Then style the rest of it using tailwind.

Although using the style property seems to work fine I stick with the tailwind className.
Based on the documentation I ended up doing this :
    const imgVariants: Record<string, string> = {
        tortue: 'bg-tortue',
        surf: 'bg-surf',
        boat: 'bg-boat',
    }

    return (
        <div
            className={`${imgVariants[symbol]} bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat aspect-[5/7] border-2 rounded-xl border-black`}
            onClick={onClickEvent}
        >
        </div>
    )

bg-* declared on imgVariants are from the tailwind.config.ts
I used the tailwind.config.ts to avoid using relative pathname.
